# Amazon Web Services EC2 Instances Become Painfully Slow From Time to Time

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the free tier for now and have noticed that the servers on which I host a couple of Wordpress sites become periodically and painfully slow to respond if I access the sites through the browser. Accessing the admin of the site becomes impossible. That said, I can still quickly SSH to the servers, if needed.

What can be causing such a behavior? I have seen short bouts of this previously but the current one has lasted for over two days. I have tried recreating the servers, rebooting them, etc. Needless to say, unless I am doing something wrong, it is making me question the decision to try AWS for these projects.

Comment: What instance types are you using? Are you running mysql locally or are you using RDS for the database component of Wordpress?

Comment: Just basic EC2. MySQL is local on each instance.

Comment: It is Amazon Linux. ^

Comment: t1.micro or t2.micro? if t2, what does the CPU credit balance look like? What does your machine utilization look like? (basically, go through the cloudwatch graphs).

Comment: t2.micro for both. I am still new to Amazon. Is it possible that they put a limit on how much I can use after a certain number of hours or other unit is exhausted?

Answer (score 5):

This is from the amazon site:

*T2 instances accrue CPU Credits when they are idle, and use CPU credits when they are active.  T2 instances are a good choice for workloads that don’t use the full CPU often or consistently, but occasionally need to burst*

Worpdress sites are CPU intensive and not suiteable for this kind of environment. I have tried it before and learned quickly that t2.micro is good for two things. Light development or cached html content. Anything beyond that you are asking for trouble.

You need to upgrade beyond the free tier if you want some results. Otherwise convert your site to a simple html website, or cache the heck out of your content.

Comment: @ArtforLife -- The best way to see whether this is the cause of your problem is to use Amazon CloudWatch to check your CPU levels, and your credit balance. See [View Amazon EC2 Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html) and [T2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html).

Comment: What would be the most optimal way if I want to have 2-3 wordpress sites and perhaps a playground server with some Apache, Postgres, Mongo, etc? Should I recreate the servers as more "complex" instances aka "not free?"

Comment: You don't have to recreate the servers. You simply stop them and change the instance type and restart them. Start with the weakest level and move up from there according to your needs. Just as suggested by others, consult CloudWatch for load profile.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have looked at those metrics and am not sure on how to interpret them. For instance, on one of my servers, the CreditBalance grew linearly from about 60 units to 140 today. Prior to that, it stayed at 125 for a few days. Before that, it rose to 125 from ~25. I tried to interpose the CreditUsage plot on it, but it does not seem to give any pattern.

Comment: @Scriptonomy I have just tried stopping these instances and switching them to, say, t2.small. It didn't solve the problem. Still impossible to access. At the same time, I read people on Quora say that t2.micro should be plenty to host a Wordpress site with under 2Million visitors a day. I am confused. If I am running into some AWS limit, what is it? I barely did anything to these instances except for some SSH and WP plugin installs.

Comment: All I can recommend right now, is for you to install The SuperCache plugin. Turn off permanently all unecessary programs, such as postfix. Use SMTP instead. Configure SuperCache to cache pages for a long time, like 90 days. Allow your instance to stabalize and accrue enough credit to function effectively.